# Contact Form not submitting

Tags: magento2, contact-form

I've got this block of code in my CMS that renders my contact form. However, It does not submit the form. Upon submit it routes to a 404.

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Do you have nay customization in contact form? I have tried but seems above block is work for me. After submit form it will redirect to contact/index/ original contact form. if you remove that page you will get 404 but form will be submit successfully.

Comment: The only customization is that we removed the phone number field. When I use it it routes back to itself now but the page title says "Customer Login."